# How to put ArrayObjectAdapter items in order

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, leanback

I am displaying multiple rows in one header and there is 5 more categories like drama and I am doing the same job for them. My question is when I set the adapter categories displaying randomly.(assuming of request speed).For example  I want the display Drama on the  first line always. I gave them id of adapter's constructor but didn't work out. Code :

```
 if (response.body().getItems().size() > 0) {

                            Log.d("Drama",""+response.body().getItems().size());
                            List<MovieItem> newMovieItems = response.body().getItems();


                            HeaderItem liveHeader = new HeaderItem("Drama");

                            LiveChannelPresenter liveChannelPresenter = new LiveChannelPresenter();
                            ArrayObjectAdapter liveRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(liveChannelPresenter);


                            for (int i = 0; i < newMovieItems.size(); i++) {
                                movieItem2 = response.body().getItems().get(i);
                                liveRowAdapter.add(movieItem2);
                            }

                            mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(0,liveHeader,liveRowAdapter));


                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.body().getItems().size() > 0) {

    Log.d("Drama",""+response.body().getItems().size());
    List<MovieItem> newMovieItems = response.body().getItems();
    //sorted:
    Arrays.sort(newMoviewItems, new Comparator() {  some condition to sort });


    HeaderItem liveHeader = new HeaderItem("Drama");

    LiveChannelPresenter liveChannelPresenter = new LiveChannelPresenter();
                        ArrayObjectAdapter liveRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(liveChannelPresenter);


    for (int i = 0; i < newMovieItems.size(); i++) {
         //note the change here \|/
           movieItem2 = newMoviewItems.get(i);
            liveRowAdapter.add(movieItem2);
    }

    mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(0,liveHeader,liveRowAdapter));
}
```